# How to get and display the levels on color or bw bitmap image

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

In Photoshop there is a tool that lets you adjust the levels of an image. I'd like to be able to do the same thing. I've seen examples online that show the levels but they are for each individual color channel (red, green, blue or alpha or CMYK) but not a combined view like in Photoshop Input Levels (see below).

Also, as a bonus is there a way to find the best shadow and highlight input level settings, basically the settings the Auto level button determines?
[image: Photoshop Adjustment Levels Dialog]

**Update:**

I think I'm closer but I'm not sure. Here is the method I pieced together. The first image is my results and the second is Photoshop results both analyzing the Google logo:

**Update 2:**

Ok I think I got it. The code is below. It's mostly working all the time, mostly.

Additional credits:
https://pixelero.wordpress.com/2008/06/19/flash-10-bitmapdatahistogram/#comment-448

My results:
[image: My results]

Photoshops results:
[image: Photoshop Results]

Levels method:

```
        /**
         * Get a histogram of the grayscale levels
         * */

        private function drawGrayscaleHistogram(bitmapImage:BitmapImage, sprite:Sprite):BitmapData {
            var grayScale:Array = [0.3086, 0.3086, 0.3086, 0, 0, 0.3086, 0.3086, 0.3086, 0, 0, 0.3086, 0.3086, 0.3086, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];
            var color:Array = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];
            var filter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(grayScale);
            var histogram:Vector.<Vector.<Number>>;
            var graphWidth:int = sprite.width;
            var graphHeight:int = sprite.height;
            var g:Graphics = sprite.graphics;
            var vector:Vector.<Number>;
            var bitmapData:BitmapData;
            var maxValue:int;
            var value:int;
            var i:int;

            // clone the bitmap
            bitmapData = bitmapImage.bitmapData.clone();

            // convert it to gray scale
            bitmapData.applyFilter(bitmapImage.bitmapData, bitmapImage.bitmapData.rect, new Point(), filter);

            // get histogram
            histogram = bitmapData.histogram();

            // since it's grayscale the red green and blue are all the same
            vector = histogram[0];

            // get the max value for drawing the graph
            for (var s:* in vector) {
                if (vector[s]>maxValue) {
                    maxValue = vector[s];
                }
            }

            //trace(maxValue);
            //maxValue = 300;

            // create white background
            g.clear();
            g.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1.0);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, graphWidth, graphHeight);

            // draw each line
            for each (value in vector) {
                g.lineStyle(1, 0);
                g.moveTo(i, graphHeight);
                g.lineTo(i++, Math.max(0.0, graphHeight-value * graphHeight/maxValue));
            }

            // assign it to bitmap data 
            // so we can resize easily if we want
            bitmapData = new BitmapData(graphWidth, graphHeight, true, 0x00000000);
            bitmapData.draw(sprite);

            return bitmapData;
        }
```

Usage:

levelsBitmapImage.source = drawGrayscaleHistogram(selectedPicture, sprite1);

<s:BitmapImage id="selectedPicture" width="100%" height="100%" 
                       scaleMode="letterbox"/>
<mx:UIComponent id="sprite1"/>
<s:BitmapImage id="thresholdGraph" width="100%" height="45"/>

Comment: Maybe combined levels refer to brightness (pixel value after conversion to black-and-white), like `0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B`.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do what that. Graphics are not my strong point.

Comment: For each pixel of image, get brightness value using formula, then increment corresponding counter (one of 256). You'll get levels distribution in those 256 counters. Draw those values as lines and you'll get levels picture like above.

Comment: I think I understand. I'll post back what I find.

Comment: I think I am getting closer but the levels are not matching. I've updated the original post with the update.

Comment: It seems that Photoshop analyses picture with white background (note the peak at 255) and your app analyses pic with transparent background. Or Photoshop's interpretation of alpha is different from yours.

Comment: I got it thanks. Occasionally on some images there's one value that's way out there. For example, [...96,173,149,33056].

Comment: Are levels matching now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pixel of image, get brightness value using formula, then increment corresponding counter (one of 256). You'll get levels distribution in those 256 counters. Draw those values as lines and you'll get levels picture like above.
(copied from comments to make proper answer)